# send values from javascript page to servlet page at run-time

Tags: java, javascript, servlets

My_javascript_page

```
window.onload = loadResTimeData;

function loadResTimData() {
var e = window.performance.getEntriesByType("resource");

if (window.console) {
    console.log("Resource Timming");

    var perf_data = "";
    var name, load, connection, request, fetch;
    for (var i in e) {
        if (e[i].name == "document") {             
            continue;
        }
        name = e[i].name.replace(/^.*\/|\.$/g, '') + ":";
        load = e[i].duration;
        request = e[i].responseEnd - e[i].requestStart;
        fetch = e[i].responseEnd - e[i].fetchStart;

        var s1={"Name": name, "CONNECTION":connection, "REQUEST":request, "LOAD":load, "FETCH":fetch};
        var String1=JSON.stringify(s1);

        console.log("Resource:" + name);
        console.log("User Time:" + load);
        console.log("Connection:" + connection);
        console.log("Request Time:" + request);
        console.log("Fetch Time:" + fetch);


        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"Final",   //Final is my servlet page
            data:String1,
            datatype: "json"
        });
       }
}
}
}
```

This code calculates different response times when a web page is loaded and sends the data back to the servlet page.

This data i am printing on console(Console.log values), I want to send it to my servlet page in json format.
I tried doing it using jquery ajax, but the value didnot get passed to my servlet page.
Now I came accross various links where many people gave example on how to do it. But problem is 
that all examples will be trigerred by clicking on the button. For that i need a form or may be some other thing
But in my application I want the data to be passed to my servlet page once the window.onload function is 
trigerred; where I dont need a form or textfield. Also please let me know what exactly do i need to call at my server end(request.getparameter(???))
 I am sharing the links i referred.

http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/04/jquery-ajax-request-response-java.html
http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2014/09/jquery-ajax-servlets-integration-building-a-complete-application.html

JSP_page

```
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
```

```
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
           <script language='JavaScript'>
               onclick=' window.onload';
```

Also I had people telling me to use cookies. I created cookies but my servlet page was not able to read it. 
Someone suggested I can use hidden fields as well.

You can understand I am a mess right now. Please help as to where am I going wrong or what do i need to do now....

Comment: I know i have written lots of stuff. In short I want to pass the values of JS to servlet; as soon as window.onload function is trigerred.

Comment: `$(document).ready(function(){$.ajax({...})})`

Comment: i still dont understand what is the purpose of this.